# How to perform a Sobol sensitivity analysis using R package "sensitivity"?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I would like to perform a Sobol sensitivity analysis using the R package "sensitivity". However, I am not sure how to create the first and second random sample `(X1, X2)` in the `sobol` function. I assume that `X1` and `X2` are both a subset of the input data, however, the final results seem to be incorrect.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(sensitivity)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
x1 = runif(100)
x2 = runif(100)
x3 = runif(100)
y = 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + x3 + rnorm(100)
data <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, y)

# Split data into training and testing sets
set.seed(234)
data_split <- initial_split(data, prop = 0.8)
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data <- testing(data_split)

# Create a linear regression model using tidymodels
lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

lm_fit <- lm_spec %>%
  fit(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = train_data)

# Define a model function
model_function <- function(x) {
  new_data <- data.frame(x1 = x[, 1], x2 = x[, 2], x3 = x[, 3])
  predict(lm_fit, new_data)$`.pred`
}

# Perform Sobol sensitivity analysis
set.seed(345)
X_index1 = sample(x=1:100, size = 50, replace = FALSE)
X_index2 = c(1:length(data$x1))[-X_index1]

sobol_results <- sobol(model = model_function, 
                       X1 = data[X_index1, -4], 
                       X2 = data[X_index2, -4], 
                       nboot = 1000, order = 2)

sobol_results
```

`sobol_results` shows that the sensitivity is in the following order: x2>x1>x3. According to the function `y = 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + x3 + rnorm(100)`, "x1" should have a higher sensitivity as it is `3 * x1`. How should I correct my code? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand of the [`sensitivity#sobol()` function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/319511), it requires the model to be written in a specific way. It expects a function that takes a matrix of inputs and returns a vector of outputs. In your case, the `model_function` appears to be defined correctly. See [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sensitivity/versions/1.28.1/topics/sobol).

But The `sobol` function also requires two sets of samples, `X1` and `X2`, which are matrices where each row is an independent realization of the inputs. They should be generated from the joint distribution of the inputs, not subsets of your existing data.

Your current code is treating `X1` and `X2` as subsets of your data, which is incorrect.

In your original code, you create `X1` and `X2` as follows:

```r
set.seed(345)
X_index1 = sample(x=1:100, size = 50, replace = FALSE)
X_index2 = c(1:length(data$x1))[-X_index1]

sobol_results <- sobol(model = model_function, 
                       X1 = data[X_index1, -4], 
                       X2 = data[X_index2, -4], 
                       nboot = 1000, order = 2)
```

That means `X_index1` and `X_index2` are created by sampling indices from your original data set. `X_index1` is a random sample of 50 indices, and `X_index2` is the set of all remaining indices. You then use these indices to subset your original data set into `X1` and `X2`.

So, `X1` and `X2` are not independent samples from the joint distribution of your input variables. Instead, they are subsets of your original data.

However, the `sobol` function in the `sensitivity` package requires `X1` and `X2` to be independent samples from the joint distribution of your input variables. This is needed because the `sobol` function uses `X1` and `X2` to systematically vary each input variable while keeping the others constant, in order to estimate the sensitivity of the model output to each input variable.

When `X1` and `X2` are subsets of your data, they do not independently cover the joint distribution of your input variables, which can lead to incorrect sensitivity estimates. This is why the Sobol sensitivity analysis results you obtained did not match your expectations based on the coefficients of your model.

You should generate `X1` and `X2` as independent samples from the joint distribution of your input variables. If your input variables are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (as they are in your example), you could generate `X1` and `X2` as follows:

```r
n <- 1000  # number of samples to generate
X1 <- matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)
X2 <- matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)
```

Then you can pass these as the `X1` and `X2` arguments to the `sobol` function.

Something like:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(sensitivity)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
x1 = runif(100)
x2 = runif(100)
x3 = runif(100)
y = 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + x3 + rnorm(100)
data <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, y)

# Split data into training and testing sets
set.seed(234)
data_split <- initial_split(data, prop = 0.8)
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data <- testing(data_split)

# Create a linear regression model using tidymodels
lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

lm_fit <- lm_spec %>%
  fit(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = train_data)

# Define a model function
model_function <- function(x) {
  new_data <- data.frame(x1 = x[, 1], x2 = x[, 2], x3 = x[, 3])
  predict(lm_fit, new_data)$`.pred`
}

# Perform Sobol sensitivity analysis
set.seed(345)
n <- 1000  # number of samples to generate
X1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3))
X2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3))

sobol_results <- sobol(model = model_function, 
                       X1 = X1, 
                       X2 = X2, 
                       nboot = 1000, order = 2)

sobol_results
```

This updated code uses the [`runif` function](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/R/functions/runif) to generate uniform random numbers for `X1` and `X2` that are representative of your input variables (assuming they are uniformly distributed). The matrices `X1` and `X2` are independent samples from the joint distribution of your input variables, which is what the `sobol` function requires.

Remember, the purpose of this is to understand how variations in the input variables influence the output of your model. The `sobol` function accomplishes this by systematically varying one parameter at a time while keeping the others fixed, and these independent samples `X1` and `X2` enable that process.

---

[user10085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6123824/user10085) asks in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76444438/how-to-perform-a-sobol-sensitivity-analysis-using-r-package-sensitivity/76458250#comment134863810_76458250):

> I was wondering how `data.frame(x1 = x[, 1], x2 = x[, 2], x3 = x[, 3])` and `matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)` can be automated to fit any dataset?

To make this code more flexible and adaptable to any dataset, you can:

- define a function that generates an independent random sample for any number of variables,
- and another function that constructs a new data frame with the same structure as your input data.

First, you would add the calculation of `num_vars` and `feature_names`: These are new steps in the updated code. `num_vars` (the number of input variables) is calculated as the number of columns in your training data minus one (to exclude the response variable), and `feature_names` (the names of the input variables) is defined as the column names of your training data excluding the response variable.
These are used to generate `X1` and `X2` with the correct number of columns, and to ensure that the new data frame created in the model function has the correct column names. These steps make the code adaptable to any dataset with any number of input variables.

```r
num_vars <- ncol(train_data) - 1  # number of input variables
feature_names <- colnames(train_data)[1:num_vars]
```

Then you update the generation of `X1` and `X2`: In the previous corrected code, `X1` and `X2` were generated with a hard-coded number of columns (3). In the updated code, they need to be generated with a number of columns equal to the number of input variables in your data. This ensures that `X1` and `X2` have the correct structure for the Sobol sensitivity analysis, regardless of the number of input variables in your data.

```r
# Previous code
X1 <- matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)
X2 <- matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)

# Updated code
num_vars <- ncol(train_data) - 1  # number of input variables
X1 <- matrix(runif(num_vars*n), ncol = num_vars)
X2 <- matrix(runif(num_vars*n), ncol = num_vars)
```

Finally, you would change the `model` function: In the previous corrected code, the model function was defined with the assumption of three input variables. It explicitly constructed a new data frame with columns `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.
In the updated code, the model function would now construct a new data frame with a number of columns equal to the number of input variables in your data, and assigns the correct column names using the `feature_names` vector. This allows the model function to work with any number of input variables.

```r
# Previous code
model_function <- function(x) {
  new_data <- data.frame(x1 = x[, 1], x2 = x[, 2], x3 = x[, 3])
  predict(lm_fit, new_data)$`.pred`
}

# Updated code
model_function <- function(x, model, feature_names) {
  new_data <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = length(feature_names)))
  colnames(new_data) <- feature_names
  predict(model, new_data)$`.pred`
}
```

The end result would be similar to:

```r
model_function <- function(x, model, feature_names) {
  new_data <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = length(feature_names)))
  colnames(new_data) <- feature_names
  rownames(new_data) <- NULL  # Reset row names to ensure they are unique
  predict(model, new_data)$`.pred`
}
```

So the full updated code will be:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(sensitivity)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
x1 = runif(100)
x2 = runif(100)
x3 = runif(100)
y = 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + x3 + rnorm(100)
data <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, y)

# Split data into training and testing sets
set.seed(234)
data_split <- initial_split(data, prop = 0.8)
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data <- testing(data_split)

# Create a linear regression model using tidymodels
lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

lm_fit <- lm_spec %>%
  fit(y ~ ., data = train_data)  # Use . to include all other variables in the formula

# Define a model function
model_function <- function(x, model, feature_names) {
  new_data <- x
  colnames(new_data) <- feature_names
  predict(model, as.data.frame(new_data))$`.pred`
}

# Set up for Sobol sensitivity analysis
n <- 1000  # Number of samples
set.seed(345)
num_vars <- ncol(train_data) - 1  # number of input variables
feature_names <- colnames(train_data)[1:num_vars]

X1 <- matrix(runif(num_vars*n), ncol = num_vars)
X2 <- matrix(runif(num_vars*n), ncol = num_vars)

# Perform Sobol sensitivity analysis
sobol_results <- sobol(model = function(x) model_function(x, lm_fit, feature_names), 
                       X1 = X1, 
                       X2 = X2, 
                       nboot = 1000, order = 2)
sobol_results
```

These modifications make the code more flexible and adaptable to different datasets with varying numbers of input variables.

Comment: @VonC I was wondering how `data.frame(x1 = x[, 1], x2 = x[, 2], x3 = x[, 3])` and `matrix(runif(3*n), ncol = 3)` can be automated to fit any dataset?

Comment: @VonC Thank you very much for updating your answer. But it returns ```Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘’ ```. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @UseR10085 That kind of error should often be due to duplicate row names in a data frame. However, the last code does not explicitly set any row names, so the error might be related to the `predict` function in the `model_function` or the `sobol` function.

One potential way to avoid this issue is to reset the row names of the data frame within the `model_function` to ensure they are unique before passing the data frame to the `predict` function. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: @VonC is the code running ok for you? I am again getting the same error.

Comment: @UseR10085 Sorry, I don't have access to a runtime environment right now. I have modified the `model` function, since the `predict` function can also take a matrix as input. I assume the error is probably caused by the `matrix` to `data.frame` conversion in the `model_function`. When a matrix is converted into a data frame, the row names of the matrix become the row names of the data frame, and in this case, they are not unique because the row names of the matrix are just the row indices.